# Doctrine DQL (Symfony2) - WHERE concatenated field is IN params

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I need to check if multiple items exists in a table. The problem is that I have to check strings in two fields concatenated togeher like if I would like to check first and last names together, but store them separately. I'm new to doctrine, and after an extensive research in the topic, I've tried two ways:

```
$params = array('two words', 'another here');

// writing the DQL
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery("
        SELECT foo.f1, foo.f2
        FROM MyCompanyMyBundle:MyEntity foo
        WHERE CONCAT(CONCAT(foo.f1, ' '), foo.f2) IN (:params)
    ")->setParameter('params', implode(', ', $params));
```

**NOTE**: Double CONCAT is required becouse CONCAT_WS is not supported by Doctrine.

This should work (imo) but :params is replaced by **one** string ( 'two words, another here' ), not a series of strings separated by a comma. (I Tried palcing individual apostrophes around the elements in $params but that doesn't work either, it gets escaped by Docrine ( '\'two words\', \'another here\'') ).

```
// trying the query builder

$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('foo');
$query = $qb
    ->select(array('foo.f1', 'foo.f2' ))
    ->where(
        $qb->expr()->in(
            $qb->expr()->concat( $qb->expr()->concat('foo.f1', ' '), 'foo.f2'),
            ':params'
        )
    )
    ->setParameter('params', implode(', ', $params))
    ->getQuery();
```

I guess I'm not even close with the query builder, so if that is the way to go I appreciate any help!

So my goal is to return the rows where the two columns values are correct together.

Which is the way to go, and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: When using `setParameter()` on a parameter in an `IN(...)` clause, you  should pass an array directly - `setParameter('params', $params)`. This may or may not solve your problem.

Comment: It works! If you post it as an answer, I gladly accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Thought there'd be more to it, but I will certainly post an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the issue is the way you're using `setParameter()` with the `IN(...)` clause - you should pass an array, rather than imploding -

```
$params = array('two words', 'another here');

// writing the DQL
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery("
        SELECT foo.f1, foo.f2
        FROM MyCompanyMyBundle:MyEntity foo
        WHERE CONCAT(CONCAT(foo.f1, ' '), foo.f2) IN (:params)
    ")->setParameter('params', $params);
```

Comment: I don't know why this isn't listed in the documentation:
[http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html#binding-parameters-to-your-query](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html#binding-parameters-to-your-query)